# Cuda copy and copy back giving random values.

Tags: cuda, gpu, gpgpu

I am trying to compute a histogram using some shared memory to improve performance. However I am running into a problem that I don't seem to figure out. Here is the kernel code i am having problem with. i am sure I am missing something silly but i can't locate it.

```
__global__
 void histogram_kernel_shared(const unsigned int* const d_vals,
                    unsigned int* d_histo,
                    const unsigned int numElems) {

    unsigned int gid = threadIdx.x + blockDim.x * blockIdx.x;
    unsigned int lid = threadIdx.x;

    unsigned int bin = d_vals[gid];
    __syncthreads();

    __shared__ unsigned int local_bin[1024];

    local_bin[lid] = d_histo[lid];
    __syncthreads();

    if(local_bin[lid] != d_histo[lid])
        printf("After copy to local. block = %u, lid = %u, local_bin = %u, d_histo = %u \n", blockIdx.x, lid, local_bin[lid], d_histo[lid]);

    __syncthreads();

    // If I comment out this line everything works fine.
    d_histo[lid] = local_bin[lid];  

    // Even this leads to some wrong answers. Printouts on the next printf.
    // d_histo[lid] = d_histo[lid];  
     __syncthreads();

    if(local_bin[lid] != d_histo[lid])
        printf("copy back. block = %u, lid = %u, local_bin = %u, d_histo = %u \n", blockIdx.x, lid, local_bin[lid], d_histo[lid]);

    __syncthreads();

    atomicAdd(&d_histo[bin], static_cast<unsigned int>(1));

    __syncthreads();

    // atomicAdd(&local_bin[bin], static_cast<unsigned int>(1));
    __syncthreads();

}
```

the kernel is launched as follows

```
threads = 1024;
blocks = numElems/threads;
histogram_kernel_shared<<<blocks, threads>>>(d_vals, d_histo, numElems);
```

number of elements is 10,240,000
and number of Bins is 1024.

What is bugging me is why should the assignment `d_histo[lid] = local_bin[lid];` make difference here. Code runs fine without it. But nothing should change by that assignemtn since I just copied the value as `local_bin[lid] = d_histo[lid];` and even more why does  `local_bin[lid] = d_histo[lid];` gives garbage values as well?

My guess is that something else is wrong somewhere else giving some odd kind of UB but Where?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Please do proper [cuda error checking](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14038589/what-is-the-canonical-way-to-check-for-errors-using-the-cuda-runtime-api) on all cuda kernel calls and API calls.  Run your code with `cuda-memcheck` to get additional information.  Finally, provide a *complete* code.  For example you haven't shown how `d_histo` is defined or allocated.  SO expects: "Questions concerning problems with code you've written must describe the specific problem — and include valid code to reproduce it — in the question itself. See SSCCE.org for guidance. "

Comment: What exactly do you mean by garbage? Random guess: `__syncthreads()` affects _only_ threads within same block, so the `d_histo[lid] = d_histo[lid]` line might be executed in following order: `thread1 reads d_histo[0]` -> `thread9000 modifies d_histo[0]` -> `thread1 writes old value of d_histo[0] back`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're launching 10,000 blocks:

```
blocks = numElems/threads;
```

*EACH BLOCK* is writing to the first 1024 (`lid`) locations of `d_histo`:

```
d_histo[lid] = local_bin[lid];
```

Since you have 10,000 blocks all writing to the same locations, they are all stepping on each other and overwriting each other.  Since the order of block execution is undefined, you'll get undefined behavior for sure.

Comment: :) I knew it was something obvious. I don't know how I couldn't see that. Thanks.